# Why ListBox doesn't have a FindString method in Excel-VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

Trying to search on a ListBox.  Specifically, I want to look at an array of items from the Cell, and for each one that matches an entry in the ListBox, I want it to select that List.
I copy-pasted some code that was supposed to let me find a string, but it keeps telling me:

> Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found.

Any suggestions?

**Relevant Code:**

```
Public local_Target As Range
    ' local_Target is assigned in the sheet function to pass it here

Private Sub Network_ListBox_Enter()
    ' Get data in cell (if any)
    Dim current_data As String
    Dim entries() As String

    current_data = local_Target.Value

    If current_data = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        entries = Split(current_data, vbNewLine)
    End If

    For Each Item In entries
        FindMyString Item
    Next Item

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim result As String

    ' Iterate through the listbox and create the result, then assign to
    ' Target.value
    For index = 0 To Network_ListBox.ListCount - 1
        If Network_ListBox.Selected(index) Then
            ' stuff
            If result = "" Then
                result = Network_ListBox.List(index)
            ' ElseIf index = Network_ListBox.ListCount - 1 Then
            '     result = result + Network_ListBox.List(index)
            Else
                result = result + vbNewLine + Network_ListBox.List(index)
            End If
        End If
    Next index

    local_Target.Value = result
End Sub

Sub FindMyString(ByVal searchString As String)
   ' Ensure we have a proper string to search for.
   If searchString <> "" Then
      ' Find the item in the list and store the index to the item.
      Dim index As Integer

      index = Me.Network_ListBox.FindString(searchString)
      ' Determine if a valid index is returned. Select the item if it is valid.
      If index <> -1 Then
         Network_ListBox.SetSelected index, True
      'Else
      '   MessageBox.Show ("The search string did not match any items in the ListBox")
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked `Intellisense` and I don't think that `Method` is supported in VBA.
 Other documentations I've found refers to `.Net Framework` only as well.
 So maybe, it is not really supported in VBA, but regardless, you can create a function to do just that. Something like below.

```
Private Function SearchString(mysearch As String, mylist As Variant) As Long
    Dim itm As Variant, idx As Long: idx = 0
    If IsArray(mylist) Then
        For Each itm In mylist
            If mysearch = itm Then
                SearchString = idx: Exit Function
            End If
            idx = idx + 1
        Next
    End If
    SearchString = -1
End Function
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    'do the search
    i = SearchString("WhatImSearching", Me.ListBox1.List)
    'select the item that match your search
    If i <> -1 Then Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True 
End Sub
```

I'm not saying that the function I created above is the most efficient way.
That is just an example to give you an idea for a workaround. HTH.

**Important:** This works in single column ListBox which have a 1D array list. If you need to work on multi-column ListBox, you'll have to tweak the function a little.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  I probably would've come up with something similar on my own given enough time.  As for the intellisense, I trust it 99% of the time; it's that 1% that really gets you.